# How to get one variable to equal multiple lines of a .txt file?

Tags: string, variables, text-files, autoit

How to get one variable to update its string value every loop? I am storing lines of a text file in a variable named `$attempt`, then I show it in a textbox.

The .txt file:

[image: pw.txt]

My AutoIt script:

[image: AutoIt Picture]

`$attempt` always equals string "dog" (first line of pw.txt), which means "dog" is entered in the textbox 5 times. I hope to get "Dog", "Apple", "Sand", "Shoes", and "Hat" entered in the textbox, all once, on their own, at different times.

How to get variable `$attempt` to equal the following line in "pw.txt" after each loop iteration (for example,

1. first iteration `$attempt` = "Dog",
2. second iteration `$attempt` = "Apple",
3. third iteration `$attempt` = "Sand", etc.)?

Lines of text are examples, subject to change.

Comment: Please paste the code and file content here, instead of the images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a file handle. At the moment you are opening the file, reading the file and closing it in each iteration of the loop. By using a file handle, the file is kept open and the next line is read.

e.g.

```
$fh=FileOpen("pw.txt")
for $i=1 to 5
 $attempt=FileReadLine($fh)
 MsgBox(4096,"test",$attempt)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the entire file into an array instead of reading each single line:

```
$aPW = FileReadToArray("pw.txt")
For $attempt In $aPW
    MsgBox(0, "test", $attempt)
Next
```

Bonus: you don't have to know beforehand how many lines there are in the file, and it's much faster, as you access the file only once.

**Attention:** Maximum number of elements for an array is 16,777,216 ([Source](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/LimitsDefaults.htm)), so when your file is bigger than 16.7 million lines, Richards answer is your way to go in spite of the speed disadvantage.